# Can WordNetLemmatizer in Nltk stem words?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet, stemming, lemmatization

I want to find word stems with `Wordnet`.  Does `wordnet` have a function for stemming? 
I use this import for my stemming, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize('Having','v')
```

Comment: @jacob - well done chap, I was just about to edit this into shape as well :)

Comment: If your input is in English, why would you want to stem when lemmas contain much more useful information about the token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using one of the stemmers in [nltk.stem](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.stem-module.html) module, such as the [PorterStemmer](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.stem.porter-module.html).  Here's an online demo of NLTK's stemmers: http://text-processing.com/demo/stem/

Comment: Thanks But PorterStemmer Is Very Old Method ... Lancaster Is newser Than Porter But I want to stem with wordnet. Thanks For Your Answer

Comment: I see this Before . it's good site for stemming. Lancaster is most stronger than porterstemmer. thank you

Answer (score 10):

Seems like you have to input a lowercase string to the `lemmatize` method:

```
>>> WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize('having','v')
'have'
>>> WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize('has','v')
'have'
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Wordnet cannot stem the words. It can only give lemmatized words i.e. words which are actual words in the language. A stemmer may not always give real meaningful words.